# prevent navigational links from resizing if page content does not occupy the height of the dipsplay

Tags: html, css, formatting

i am developing my first website for which i have navigational links at the top of every page. i noticed some very peculiar behaviour of the site which is : pages whose height is greater than or equal to the max vertical pixels, occupy a certain width, while pages whose content does not fill the height, have a different width even though the code for the menu is exactly the same.why does this happen and what is the remedy? here is the code:
html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>About</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about_style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li id="home"><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li id="news"><a href ="../news/index_news.html">News</a></li>
                <li id="tragic_complexity"><a href="../tragic/index_tr.html">Tragic Complexity</a></li>
                <li id="d_diary"><a href="../diary/d_diary.html">D Diary</a></li>
                <li id="geeks"><a href="../geeks/geeks.html">Geeks = 1</a></li>
                <li id="about">About</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <ul id="info">
        <li>
            About the site
        </li>
        <li>
            About the founder
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
body
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(#336666, #66cccc);

}
#info,#menu
{
    text-align:center;
}
#info li
{
        display:block;
        font-family:serif;
        height:300px;
        width:600px;
        border:1px solid black;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        margin:20px auto 20px auto;
        background-color:white;
}
#menu ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:auto 20px auto 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible that this is simply due to the fact that a vertical scrollbar is introduced on those longer pages and not on the others. If you want to remove this behavior, you can force the scroll bar to be added regardless of content height.

Check these links on how:

http://egilhansen.com/2007/03/28/css-trick-always-show-scrollbars

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/

From the first link:

```
html {
     overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
     overflow: scroll;
}
```